# How to amend an entry on a form without eliciting an EConvertError?

Tags: delphi

I have two labeled edit boxes - one for a min value (named lbleRangeCalcMin) and the other for a max value (lbleRangeCalcMax).  I want to make sure that the user does not enter a zero for the max value and also that the min value is less than the max value (not equal to, but less than - I need the range of values: max - min).

I want to catch the error as soon as it happens (for e.g., as soon as the user enters a zero for the max value).  I also don't want the user to be able to move away from the max value if s/he has entered a zero.  So I have programmed exception calls on the two events, OnChange and OnExit.

It works fine except when the user tries to reenter another value instead of the zero that he entered.  Then it gives me an EConvertError with the message: '' is not a floating point value.

How do I allow the user to amend his entry without raising this exception?  Here is my code.  Thanks.

```
procedure TfrmAnalysisOptions.lbleRangeCalcMaxChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if ((StrToFloat((lbleRangeCalcMax.Text) = 0) or
      (StrToFloat((lbleRangeCalcMax.Text) <
        StrToFloat((lbleRangeCalcMin.Text))) then
     MessageDlg('Max value cannot be zero or less than Min value.', mtError,
        [mbOK], 0);
end;



procedure TfrmAnalysisOptions.lbleRangeCalcMaxExit(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if ((StrToFloat(lbleRangeCalcMax.Text) = 0) or
      (StrToFloat(lbleRangeCalcMax.Text) <
        StrToFloat(lbleRangeCalcMin.Text))) then
     MessageDlg('Max value cannot be zero or less than Min value.', mtError,
        [mbOK], 0);
end;
```

Comment: Don't use `OnExit` events for data validation. As for avoiding `EConvertError`, use `TryStrToFloat()` instead.

Comment: But the user should really not be navigating to another data input if the first entry is invalid.  I thought the OnExit event catches such transgressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TryStrToFloat()` to avoid the `EConvertError` exceptions:

```
var
  RangeMin, RangeMax: Double;
begin
  if not TryStrToFloat(lbleRangeCalcMax.Text, RangeMax) then Exit;
  if RangeMax = 0 then
  begin
     MessageDlg('Max value cannot be zero.', mtError, [mbOK], 0);
     Exit;
  end;
  if not TryStrToFloat(lbleRangeCalcMin.Text, RangeMin) then Exit;
  if RangeMax < RangeMin then
     MessageDlg('Max value cannot be less than Min value.', mtError, [mbOK], 0);
end;
```

Comment: I also liked how you neatly separated the two errors.  So the TryStrToFloat is a catch-all (for all the possible reasons why the string could not be converted to a float?)  Seems like I will need to write code for that exception too, for at present it simply exits the procedure.